# Move string to end of file assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-16, dos, tasm

I need to move my message string to the end of program and the program need to output it correctly. How can I do that?

```
.model small
.stack 100h

.data

.code
main:
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

output:
    jmp message
    MOV dx, offset message
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h

    mov ah, 4Ch
    int 21h


message:
 db 'Hello, World!', '$'

end main
```

Comment: `jmp message` is certainly wrong. You don't want to have the machine interpret your text as machine language instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to move my message string to the end of program and the program need to output it correctly.

The way I understand this is, that you don't want your message string to be part of the `.data` section, but rather reside in the `.code` section.
Your current solution (?) `jmp message` can't help you as it will bypass the one thing that *can* output your string, and worse, it will begin executing garbage instructions formed by whatever bytes happen to be in the message string.
The `jmp message` clearly has to go, but there is one change that is required. The DOS.PrintString function 09h always expects a far pointer to the $-terminated string in the registers DS:DX, so you need to **copy CS to DS** since the string now resides in the code segment. That's all!

```
main:
    push cs
    pop  ds
    mov  dx, offset message
    mov  ah, 09h
    int  21h

    mov  ax, 4C00h
    int  21h

message: db 'Hello, World!$'

end main
```